# How do I calculate the sum of neighboring result pairs, and subsequent pairs in succession?

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the sum of neighboring two results returned by a MySQL query. 
Since I need to calculate the sum of neighboring two results, I need to take the result of the first column and then add it to the second, then I need to take the result of the second column and add it to the third... so on an so forth.

I tried to use the *static* keyword but it did not work as expected.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($test as $key=>$value){
static $q;
  $q = $sum+= $value;
}
echo $q;
```

Schema:

[image]

When I use `var_dump($test)`, results are:

```
 array(13) { [0]=> string(5) "21.00" [1]=> string(5) "19.00" [2]=> string(5) "24.00" [3]=> string(6) "277.00" [4]=> string(5) "22.00" [5]=> string(5) "23.00" [6]=> string(5) "21.00" [7]=> string(5) "17.00" [8]=> string(5) "24.00" [9]=> string(5) "21.00" [10]=> string(5) "24.00" [11]=> string(5) "22.00" [12]=> string(5) "22.00" }
```

Comment: How does `$test` look like? Can you do `var_dump($test);` and paste the output within your question please.

Comment: @caramba edited

Comment: What kind of database query gives you this weird of a result array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Looking at your schema and `var_dump` result, the solution would be like this:</strike>

```
$nthIndex = count($test) - 1;
$count = count($test[$nthIndex]);
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
    $sum = $test[$nthIndex][$i] + $test[$nthIndex][$i + 1]; // sum of current and next value
    // your code. For example, echo $sum . '<br />';
}
```

---

You should consider refactoring the SQL query to get a neat result set.

### Update:

As I suspected, the weird array is because OP is doing `var_dump($test);` inside a loop. The actual output of `var_dump($test);` looks like this,

```
array(13) {
    [0] => string(5) "21.00" 
    [1] => string(5) "19.00" 
    [2] => string(5) "24.00" 
    [3] => string(6) "277.00"
    ...
```

So based on the output, the solution would be like this,

```
$count = count($test);
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
    $sum = $test[$i] + $test[$i + 1];
    // your code. For example, echo $sum . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: It shows me nothing, It does not go in for loop at all

Comment: @Pablo Did you do `echo $sum . '<br />';` inside `for` loop? Is it showing nothing?

Comment: @Pablo Perhaps your array structure is different that what portrait's in the question, please see this [live example](https://eval.in/1042620). Please do `var_dump($test);`, paste the complete output on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: Why do I have so weird array?

Comment: @Pablo It seems you are doing `var_dump($test);` inside any loop, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177006/discussion-between-pablo-and-rajdeep-paul).

Comment: Can you still help me with this question? I have one problem